# Base64 encode questions related to WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, var

I have 2 variables in WordPress I'm concatenating and then "trying" to convert to Base64.

I have this as part of a greater script that I ported to WordPress as a plugin and it all works fine, however, that version does not comply with WP standards, nor does it add the new functionality, I've created. In adding the new functionality, I've had to abandon my original JS. Now I need to reproduce this last JS function (btoa).

> Before going further - var1 and var2 are pre-encrypted codes used for a remote OAuth server - not for WordPress.
> That server needs these codes to be Base64 Encoded to connect.

I have them concatenated, but am unable to convert the resulting variable to Base64. I've tried both the following lines of code:

```
$concatenated = $var1 . ":" . $var2; //This works fine - only here for reference   
base64_encode($concatenated); //I figured this would not work in WordPress
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$concatenated = btoa($concatenated);</script>'; //I thought this would work, but it does nothing
```

Any snippet or example would be great for this one liner.
I've researched and found many solutions that required a great deal of reading but ended with no working solution. This (as I see it) should be a simple one liner to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you looking for a WP compliant Base64_encode solution, I found it through trial and error...

```
$concatenated = base64_encode(htmlentities($concatenated, ENT_QUOTES));
```